# I want to know the time taken by an action in jsp. how to do that?

Tags: javascript, jsp-tags

```
<a  onclick="javascript:submitForm('save.htm');">
<span>Save</span></a>
```

In the above code when i click on save 
I want to store the time taken by the save.htm action to to save all the inputs.
Kindly help.

Comment: How does that have anything to do with jsp?

Comment: m calling the action from jsp. want to add timer in jsp itself . is their any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet that you provide shows that the code is invoked from the Javascript within the browser. The browser will submit the form.
If you want to see how long it takes to process the save from the client perspective which include the submission time back and fro from the browser, you just need to add alerts that display the time.

For debugging purpose, for example you can do this:

```
<a  onclick="javascript:var start=new Date();submitForm('save.htm'); stop=new Date(); alert('start: ' + start + '\nstop: ' + stop);">
<span>Save</span></a>
```

You can create some fancy Javascript code to put the result in proper place instead of using alert dialog box.

On the other hand, if you want to know what exactly it took to process at the server side, the one who should log is the "save.htm" page, which should print the starting and the stop time, and you can also calculate the difference between them.

For example, the simplest (not recommended for production) would be adding this scriptlet into your JSP where save.htm is processing (assuming "save.htm" is a JSP, not a controller class):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();    
// do the processing here
process();
saveHereAndThere();
long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();    
System.out.println("The processing took: " + (stop - start) + "milliseconds.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to examine server logs - you may need to configure logging system   depending on web framework you are using.   If server logs are not accessigble, you can use 
browser debugging tools to time complete network roundtrip

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bit of work, but have you tried [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/oop-benchmark/13) ?